# Hibernate confusion. What are the differences between ga, GA and Final Releases? Compatibility? Repository?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, compatibility

Can anyone please explain:

1. The difference between ga, GA and Final Hibernate releases?

2. Should I use the maven repository or the jboss nexus repository?

3. Why does the latest compatibility matrix (http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix) not list anything higher than 3.2.6GA?

I'm using the following versions and I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out if I should upgrade:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The difference between ga, GA and Final Hibernate releases?

Final is the "new" [JBoss convention](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProjectVersioning) and replaces the old GA (for *General Availability*) convention.

> Should I use the maven repository or the jboss nexus repository?

Ultimate versions of JBoss artifacts might not be available in the *central* repository. If you want to use ultimate versions (e.g. Hibernate 3.5.3-Final), use the [JBoss Nexus repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public).

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

> Why does the latest [compatibility matrix](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix) not list anything higher than 3.2.6GA?

Well, for versions prior to 3.5, **it does**!

As of version 3.5.x versions, there is no need for the compatibility matrix anymore since Hibernate Core, Hibernate Annotations and  Hibernate EntityManager are released together.

> I'm using the following versions and I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out if I should upgrade:

If you want to use the ultimate JPA 1.0 version of Hibernate Entity Manager, simply declare the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.O.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

And you will get other artifacts transitively.